# how resolve fish: Unable to open temporary file '/opt/PhpStorm-191.6707.66/plugins/terminal/fish/fishd.tmp.6SUNyz': Permission denied

Tags: permission-denied, fish

```
<E> fish: Unable to open temporary file '/opt/PhpStorm-191.6707.66/plugins/terminal/fish/fishd.tmp.OVntXJ': Permission denied
<E> fish: Unable to open temporary file '/opt/PhpStorm-191.6707.66/plugins/terminal/fish/fishd.tmp.DygYJ9': Permission denied
<E> fish: Unable to open temporary file '/opt/PhpStorm-191.6707.66/plugins/terminal/fish/fishd.tmp.6SUNyz': Permission denied
<E> fish: Unable to open temporary file '/opt/PhpStorm-191.6707.66/plugins/terminal/fish/fishd.tmp.pOdNNZ': Permission denied
<E> fish: Unable to open temporary file '/opt/PhpStorm-191.6707.66/plugins/terminal/fish/fishd.tmp.cGU75p': Permission denied
<E> fish: Unable to open temporary file '/opt/PhpStorm-191.6707.66/plugins/terminal/fish/fishd.tmp.uELMoQ': Permission denied
<E> fish: Unable to open temporary file '/opt/PhpStorm-191.6707.66/plugins/terminal/fish/fishd.tmp.xQyTHg': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 2):

This is [a long-standing bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-189670) in Intellij's fish integration.

Deactivate it in Tools -> Terminal -> "Shell Integration".